# Understanding a theorem of isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, isometry

*Theorem*. Let $T$ be a length-preserving linear transformation. Then either the matrix of $T$ is $\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -sin\theta \\ sin\theta & cos\theta \end{pmatrix}$ for some number $\theta$ and then $T$ is rotation $R_\theta$, or else the matrix of $T$ is $\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & sin\theta \\ sin\theta & -cos\theta \end{pmatrix}$, and then $T$ is reflection through the line through the origin which forms an angle of $\theta /2$ with the positive $x-axis$.

**My question is**: I didn't understand the theorem that what is ''the the matrix of $T$ is $\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -sin\theta \\ sin\theta & cos\theta \end{pmatrix}$ etc.''  mean? And how ca I use the therem in the isometry of the plane, can you give an axeample for using the theoerem?

Comment: What do you not understand about the theorem? Do you know what a linear transformation is? Do you know what the matrix of a linear transformation is? Do you know what it means to write a matrix with $\theta$ in it "for some number $\theta$"? Do you know what the word "or" means? Please be more specific about where you ran into trouble.

Comment: Look up "The matrix of a linear transformation" anywhere.

Comment: @DavidK Actuallyi I didn't understand anyting. I know linear transformation. I don't know what the matrix of  a linear transformation. I don't know what it means to write a matrix with $\theta$ in it ''for some number $\theta$''.

Comment: I suggest you go back a few pages in the textbook to where it first mentions a matrix and see if that part makes any sense. If it does not, you can ask a question about the part that didn't make sense there; but if you can understand the definition of the matrix of a linear transformation, see if this theorem makes more sense. You might at least be able to ask a more focused question that doesn't ask someone to write a chapter of a textbook on transformation matrices for you.

Answer (score 0):

This may not constitute a full answer to your question, but may provide some food for thought.

Suppose that $T$ is the $2 \times 2$ matrix of a linear transformation. The value of the determinant of $T$ tells several important things about the transformation.

1. The absolute value of the determinant tells the area scaling factor of the transformation:

If $R$ is a region of the plane and $R'$ is its image, then area of $R′ = | \det(T) | \cdot A(R)$, where $A(R)$ is the area of the region $R$.

(For example, if $\det(T) = 12$, every region is mapped to a region that is $12$ times as large.)

2. If $\det(T) > 0$, then the transformation is orientation preserving. That is, $R$ and $R′$ will have the same orientation.

For example, all rotations above have a positive determinant, which you can find out for yourself.

3. If $\det(T) < 0$, then the transformation is orientation reversing. That is, $R$ and $R′$ will have
   opposite orientations.

For example, all reflections have a negative determinant, again you can check this above, for yourself.

4. If $\det(T) = 0$, then the transformation maps the plane to either a line or a point.

For example, all projections have a zero determinant.